# Getting modified times from remote files using curl

Tags: php, curl

Im trying the get modified times from files in a remote location but when I use curl the script stops with no errors. Im not sure where I went wrong. I have a foreach loop that brings in data from an array and puts it into a list with the filename and the date modified. Below is my code. If I put a single filename for the $curl variable it works just fine but of course repeats the same date modified for each file. Each file should have it's own modfied date and time.

```
$ftp_server   = '';
$ftp_port     = ;
$ftp_timeout  = ;
$ftp_user     = '';
$ftp_password = '';

// set up a connection or die
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server, $ftp_port, $ftp_timeout);
if ($conn_id===false) {
    echo 'Failed to connect to the server<br />';
    exit(1);
}
$logged_in = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_password);
if ($logged_in!==true) {
    echo 'Failed to log-in<br />';
    exit(1);
}
ftp_pasv ($conn_id, true);

$files = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");
if ($files===false) {
    echo 'Failed to get listing<br />';
    exit(1);
}

    if (is_array($files)) {
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<th>Detector Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Date Modified</th>";
        foreach ($files as $reader) {
            $curl = curl_init($reader);

//don't fetch the actual page, you only want headers
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);

//stop it from outputting stuff to stdout
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// attempt to retrieve the modification date
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);

$resultt = curl_exec($curl);

if ($resultt === false) {
    die (curl_error($curl)); 
}

$timestamp = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_FILETIME);
            //$readerlink= str_replace($aeiFileLocation.'/', '', $reader);
            $link= rtrim($reader,'.xml');

            //$xml_file = file_get_contents($reader, FILE_TEXT);
            
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><a href='aei.php?report=current&a=$reader'>".$link."</a></td>&nbsp;<td>".date("m/d/y H:i:s.", $timestamp)."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

        }
    }
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: The idea that a remote file mod timestamp will be reliable, let alone useful, is quite difficult to wield. However, specifically in your case you should probably rely on the ftp reaponses rather than using curl, because more than likely you will get the mod time same as current timestamp more often than not. This is typically because HTTP headers are rarely reflective of actual system time. For example, try [ftp_mdtm](https://www.php.net/ftp_mdtm) as an alternative and see if that works better.

Comment: The only reason Im using FTP is to get a list of files in a directory on a remote server. The files are generated with the same filenames and updated every so often as new data is generated from a program. I need to have the modified times inorder to write data to a database when the file modified time is newer than than what is currently in the database

Comment: You'd probably be better off using something like [fsync](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fsync) then as long as you have ssh access to the remote host.